# What is the difference between 抽烟 (chōu yān) and 吸烟 (xī yān) which both pertain to smoking?

Tags: word-choice, difference, synonyms

**Question**: What is the difference between 抽烟 (chōu yān) and 吸烟 (xī yān) which both pertain to smoking?

I‘ve ordinarily asked people

> 你抽烟吗 (nǐ chōu yān ma = "do you smoke?")

for which nobody has acted oddly about (at least, in regards to my Chinese), so I assumed it was correct, but maybe

> 你吸烟吗 (nǐ xī yān ma = "do you smoke?")

is synonymous.

However, I ordinarily see

> 禁止吸烟 （jìn zhǐ xī yān = "smoking is forbidden")

on No Smoking signs, e.g.

[image: 禁止吸烟 No smoking]

which, up until recently, I thought said

> 禁止抽烟 (jìn zhǐ chōu yān = "smoking is forbidden" [presumably])

but this is incorrect, and it doesn't seem to be commonly used (possibly even an invalid phrase).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Basically they have the same meaning and could be used interchangeably.

The subtle difference is, `抽烟` is used in spoken language more than `吸烟`. As you said, when asking people we usually say `你抽烟吗`; of course `你吸烟吗` is correct too.

On the other hand, `吸烟` is more formal and used in written language more. As you've seen, for a slogon `吸烟` is used usually; `禁止抽烟` is not wrong, but not used in general.

Answer (score 0):

Looks to me like maybe 你抽烟吗 is "Do you smoke in general?" and 你吸烟吗 is "Are you smoking right now?"  But I'm often wrong.